# Capybara testing of sinatra app fails

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, sinatra, capybara, minitest

I am trying to test a sinatra app using minitest and capybara but get several errors on all tests using capybara features like fill_in or visit.

test_index gives:

> undefined local variable or method `app' for #

test_create_user gives:

> Invalid expression: .////form[@id = 'register']

test_same_email gives:

> Unable to find css "#register"

test_login gives:

> cannot fill in, no text field, text area or password field with id,
>   name, or label 'email' found

Any suggestions on what may be wrong?

## test.rb

```
require "test/unit"
require "minitest/autorun"
require "capybara"
require "capybara/dsl"
require "rack/test"
require_relative "../lib/kimsin.rb"

ENV["RACK_ENV"] = "test"

class KimsinTests < Test::Unit::TestCase
  include Rack::Test::Methods
  include Capybara::DSL
  Capybara.app = Sinatra::Application

  def test_index
    visit "/"
    assert stuff..
  end

  def test_create_user
    visit "/user/new"
    within "//form#register" do
      fill_in :username, :with => "first@company.com"
      fill_in :password, :with => "abC123?*"
      fill_in :confirm_password, :with => "abC123?*"
      click_link "Register"
    end
    assert stuff..
  end
end
```

I'm using cygwin 1.7.15-1 on windows 7, rvm -v 1.14.1 (stable) and ruby -v 1.9.2p320.

----UPDATE----

Finally I got the tests work by incorporating Steve's suggestions:

```
within "form#register" do
fill_in "email", :with => "first@company.com"
click_button "Register"
```

and asserting the response by using capybara_minitest_spec:

```
page.must_have_content "Password"
page.must_have_button "Register"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just answered a more recent question you posted about Sintra with Webrat.

[Acceptance testing of sinatra app using webrat fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11056071/acceptance-testing-of-sinatra-app-using-webrat-fails/11066685#11066685)

I think the problem here is the same. Try replacing:

```
Capybara.app = Sinatra::Application
```

with:

```
Capybara.app = Kimsin
```

Personally I would choose Capybara over Webrat.

Comment: Unfortunately, the errors didn't change. Neither `Capybara.app = Kimsin.new` or the code above did make any change. The problem is probably either in my code (app or test) or there is a mismatch in the versions maybe.

Comment: I can't see what is going wrong in `test_index` because you have not included the assertion code. In `test_create_user` `within "//form#register" do` should be `within "form#register" do` - you seem to be mixing up xpath and css style expressions here. Finally I think that you will find that Capybara requires strings arguments for selectors so `fill_in :email ...` should be `fill_in 'email' ...` etc.

Comment: All tests (including webrat) pass with your suggestions. Thanks a lot!